# How to add a JSON object / model into your whitestorm world / scene?

Tags: models, three.js, objects

I am loading the object from my json file.

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
loader.load("blue-car.json",
function ( car ) {
  car.position.set(2, 0, 0);
  car.addTo(world);
 }
);
```

[image: Chrome Console Error]

How can I add the object to my world? In regular three.js it works when I load the json file, but how do I do it in whitestorm?

Update: I tried using the importScene whitestorm method. No errors but it still doesn't show up. Here is an image of logging out a regular plane in whitestorm and the car that is loaded from the json file.[image]

Thank You!

Comment: Are you certain the problem is loading the JSON object? The error you posted statesthat `.addTo` isn't a function of `car` - but it didn't throw an error for `car.position.set` which suggests that it did load & that it was able to access its `position` function or attribute...

Comment: So it did load the object because I can log it and set a position property on it. However it does not load into the scene when I try using the addTo method. I tried the importScene method and I don't get any errors but it still does not load into the scene.

Comment: which version of whitestormjs are you using? Can you contact me in discord chat of whitestormjs? I'll try to help

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the `THREE.ObjectLoader`, use `JSONLoader`, instead.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information? Why should asker use JSONLoader, instead?